# Ist „ka“ ein österreichisches „kein“?

Tags: austrian

<sup>**Hinweis**: Optimal sagt oder schreibt man nicht so, wie es im Titel steht. Ich bin dessen bewusst und habe womöglich versucht, einen aussagekräftigeren, richtigen Titel zu suchen. Weil eine Veränderung des Titels beide, eine Antwort hier und [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/was-ist-mit-%C3%96sterreichisch-gemeint-in-sprachlicher-hinsicht?lq=1) betroffen würde, versichte ich im Moment auf die.</sup>

---

Auf der Straße sah ich [dieses lustige Bild](http://www.wien.gv.at/umwelt/ma48/sauberestadt/sauberkeitskampagne2015.html):

[image]

Aus einem ähnlichen Bild, nur „Dafür gibt’s kan Applaus“ betitelt, und der Tatsache dass *Applaus* in Akkusativ steht, und das es mähnlich ist, rate ich mal, *ka*  ist so was wie *kein*. Stimmt?

Comment: Stimmt. Aber "ka" funktioniert für alle Genera.

Comment: Ohne Bayrisch zu können würde ich auch annehmen, dass das 'n' in 'kan' eher an dem folgenden Vokal liegt. Aber das ist geraten.

Comment: Nein, _kan_ bedeutet keine**n**. Als Gegenbeispiel biete ich zB "Keine Arbeit" = Ka Oabeit.

Comment: Danke! Bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob das Beispiel genügt, wenn "Oabeit" wie Du andeutest mit einem Diphtong beginnt.

Comment: Ka Ahnung ... :-) Im Plural wird daraus übrigens kan**e** = keine (Kane Wöll'n = keine Wellen = nur keine Aufregung)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Im Bayrischen wäre es übrigens "koa" und "koan".

Comment: @c.p. Du kannst nicht einfach im Nachhinein eine Frage ändern, die jemand so, wie sie ursprünglich gestellt hat, bereits beantwortet hat. Deine ursprüngliche Frage lautete »Ist „ka“ ein österreichisches „kein“?« Meine (wie ich glaube völlig korrekte) Antwort auf diese ursprüngliche Frage ist »eigentlich nein« (siehe unten). Im Licht der neue Frage (»Bedeutet "ka" in Wien "kein"?«) schaut meine Antwort nun falsch aus, weil meine Antwort ja auch gar nicht die neue (und inhaltlich andere) Frage beantwortet, sondern eben die ursprüngliche.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ja gut, was ist schlechter? Der Titel lautete einfach "Ist "ka" ein österreichisches »kein«". Und dann stellst Du die Frage über *Österreichisch*, wobei ich quasi beschuldigt werde, diese Frage sei dafür verantwortlich *Österreichisch* als nicht völlig richtigen Begriff zu verwenden.

Comment: @c.p. Schlecht ist eine Frage zu stellen, die man eigentlich so, wie man sie geschrieben hat, nicht gemeint hat. Man sollte schon gleich zu beginn genau das fragen was man wirklich wissen will. Schlechter ist aber, dann, wenn man aufgrund der erhaltenen Antworten erkannt hat, dass die gestellte Frage neue Fragen aufwirft, diese originale Frage zu löschen und durch eine andere zu ersetzen. Besser wäre gewesen, die Frage - gerade weil sie der Anlass neuer Fragen ist - so stehen zu lassen und eventuell die Folgefrage zu thematisieren.

Comment: @c.p.: Und ja: In deiner ursprüngliche Frage hast du das Wort »österreichisch« als nicht völlig richtigen Begriff verwendet. Ich kann nur nicht verstehen, warum du das so persönlich nimmst, wenn ich dann versuche den Begriff richtigzustellen. Niemand wirft die vor, den Begriff böswillig falsch verwendet zu haben. Das Problem ist ja gerade, dass fast alle diesen Begriff so verwenden wie du ihn verwendet hast. Und gerade weil so viele den Begriff falsch verwenden halte ich es für wichtig, das mal richtig zu stellen.

Comment: @c.p.: Sag mal, dir ist schon bewusst, dass "in Österreich" und "österreichisch" nicht dasselbe sind? Bitte lass einfach die ursprüngliche Frage »**Ist „ka“ ein österreichisches „kein“?**« stehen, dann kann jeder die darauf gegebenen Antworten und die weiteren Reaktionen nachvollziehen. Mir ist jetzt schon klar, dass du "in Österreich" oder "in Wien" gemeint hast, aber ich kann leider nicht hellsehen, und habe daher nicht die Frage beantwortet die du gemeint hast, sondern die, die du gestellt hast. Also lass bitte die ursprüngliche Frage stehen. - Danke!

Comment: Ja, super, danke! Und mit dem Hinweis wird auch klar worum es geht. Danke!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ja, das ist österreichischer (Wiener) Dialekt. Die Magistratsabteilung 48 (=MA 48), jener Teil der Wr. Stadtverwaltung der für die Abfallbeseitigung verantwortlich ist, hat immer wieder mehr oder weniger [originelle Werbungen](https://www.google.at/search?q=MA%2048%20werbung&sa=X&es_sm=93&biw=1280&bih=855&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ei=aREDVcDTG4G0UfC9g1A&ved=0CB4QsAQ). Auf den Mistkübeln (Abfallbehältern) finden sich Slogans wie "Für jeden Dreck zu haben", "Gebaut nach dem Reinheitsgebot von 2009" oder "Willst Du mich veraschen?". Eine der letzten Kampagnen lief unter dem Aufhänger "Wo samma daham?" (Wo sind wir zu Hause?), nun geht es eben bereits um den bevorstehenden ["Euro Wischn" Songcontest](http://www.wien.gv.at/umwelt/ma48/beratung/fruehjahrsputz.html).

Comment: Es gibt keinen österreichischen Dialekt. In Österreich gibt ein breites Dialekt-Kontinuum, und die in Wien gesprochenen Dialekte (es sind mehrere) gehören da dazu. Aber keine Ausprägung irgend eines Dialekts ist österreichisches Deutsch. Österreichisches Deutsch ist eine standardisierte Hochsprache, deren Regeln (die übrigens von den Regeln des Deutschen Deutsch und des Schweizerischen Deutsch geringfügig abweichen) im ÖWB festgehalten sind. (ÖWB = Österreichisches Wörterbuch = Standard-Wörterwörterbuch für Österreichisches Deutsch)

Comment: Man kann es mit der I-Tüpferl-Reiterei auch übertreiben... Ich habe ohnehin _Wiener_ Dialekt präzisiert, und was auch immer Linguisten dazu sagen (bin mit dem Letztstand der Lehre nicht im Detail vertraut) gibt es in der öffentlichen (auch: Selbst-) Wahrnehmung durchaus so etwas wie "den" Wiener Dialekt; wobei natürlich zwischen, sagen wir, Meidlinger und Schönbrunner Aussprache gewaltige Unterschiede liegen. Das würde hier aber zu weit führen. Dass Du eine Lanze für das österreichische Deutsch an sich brichst ehrt Dich, ist hier aber verfehlt; niemand hat dessen Existenz in Frage gestellt.

Comment: Es ist aber auf keinen Fall ein reines Wiener Dialekt-Wort. Ich lebe in der Steiermark und auch hier is der Gebrauch von "ka/kan/kane" in aller Munde.

Comment: Ja, natürlich. Deswegen sagte ich ja "österreichischer" bzw. Wiener Dialekt. Aber, wie auch immer: die Antwort auf die ursprüngliche Frage lautet in jedem Fall "Ja".

Answer (score 5):

### eigentlich nein

»Ka« ist kein Wort aus dem Wortschatz des österreichischen Deutsch. Österreichisches Deutsch ist nämlich eine der drei Standard-Varietäten der deutschen Hochsprache, wie sie an Schulen unterrichtet wird, wie sie in Zeitungen gedruckt und von Nachrichtensprechern in Radio und Fernsehen gesprochen wird. »Ka« ist kein Wort dieser Sprache. Man wird es im Österreichischen Wörterbuch nicht finden, es wird in einem Schulaufsatz als Fehler angestrichen und in den Nachrichten wird man es – wenn überhaupt – nur in Form eines wörtlichen Zitats hören.

### aber

»Ka« ist aber ein Wiener Dialekt-Wort, und dieses Plakat hängt auch in Wien und richtet sich an die in Wien lebende Bevölkerung, die eben genau diesen Dialekt spricht. In Österreich werden viele verschiedene Dialekte gesprochen. Die Wortwahl, Grammatik und Färbung der Aussprache ändert sich, wenn man aufmerksam hinhört, alle paar Dutzend Kilometer, und es gibt sogar in Wien mehrere verschiedene Dialekte, die nebeneinander existieren, aber »ka« hört man in den Arbeiterbezirken Simmering und Favoriten genau so wie in der Nobelgegend Döbling.

Die hochdeutsche Übersetzung für »ka« ist, wie natürlich richtig vermutet wurde, »kein«.

Comment: Ist das wirklich nur im Wiener Dialekt bekannt? Ich dachte immer, dass es in allen bairischen Dialekten so vorkommt.

Comment: @Takkat Im süddeutschen Raum wäre das eher "koa"/"koan".

Comment: @Takkat: Ich habe nicht behauptet »ka« wäre **nur** im Wiener Dialekt bekannt. Tatsächlich habe ich in Bezug auf das Wort »ka« über keine anderen Dialekte außen den Wiener Dialekten irgend eine Aussage gemacht. Daher ist es auch nicht zulässig, aus meiner Antwort Schlüsse über die Verbreitung von »ka« in anderen Dialekten zu ziehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: *"»Ka« ist aber ein Wiener Dialekt-Wort"* liest sich schon so, als hätten es die Wiener erfunden, was aber nicht stimmt. Es wird **auch** in Wien benutzt, aber findet sich in unterschiedlichen Färbungen auch in anderen **[bairischen Dialekten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte)**, zu denen natürlich auch Wienerisch zählt.

Comment: Auch nicht zulässig wäre, aus Deiner Erklärung, dass österreichisches Standarddeutsch existiert und verschieden von den Dialekten ist, zu folgern, dass Du dächtest, das wüsste hier nicht schon jeder.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Damit hast du recht. Und weil das viele nicht wissen, habe ich diese neue Frage gestellt und dazu auch eine ausführliche Antwort geschrieben: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/was-ist-mit-Österreichisch-gemeint-in-sprachlicher-hinsicht

Answer (score 5):

To keep it short:

> ka = kein, keine
>
> kan = keinen
>
> kans = keines
>
> kana = keiner
>
> kane = keine, Plural

Comment: kane = keine, Plural

Comment: thx. added this to my answer

Comment: KA is an abbreviation for Keine Ahnung, used as internet slang

Comment: @Binkan Salaryman: Not in the given context. 
"Ka tolles Publikum" doesn't mean "Keine Ahnung tolles Publikum", it means "Kein tolles Publikum". It's Austrian dialect. K.A. is only used on the Internet (and there not very much in Austria)

Comment: I was writing in context of native german, as spoken in germany. It may not be valid in austrian german, though.

Comment: @kappadoky: Maybe is would be Austrian Dialect, if there was something like »the Austrian Dialect«. But it's not. There are many different dialects in Austria, non of them may the called »the Austrian Dialect«. And most of this dialects spoken in Austria are also spoken in Bavaria, so they are not typically for Austria. For a broader Discussion of this topic see: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/was-ist-mit-Österreichisch-gemeint-in-sprachlicher-hinsicht

Comment: Of course there isn't such a thing as "the Austrian Dialect", but many dialects of austria (and bavaria) are similar. This question is related to a poster from vienna, where this translations are valid. (they are also valid in styria and many other parts of austria)